# Are OLEDs in cell phone applications able to be restored?

Tags: oled

OLED displays on cellphones have a display burn in, which creates colormetric non-uniformity in the display.  Is this degredation recoverable?

There are applications which display bright constant color fields in sequences which claim to restore displays.  However there are also claims that these may not work, and tend to lower the luminence of the display as they reduce visible degradation.

Comment: Sounds like snake oil. How are you supposed to reverse entropy through mere software?

Comment: Burn in is caused by OLED pixels being switched on for longer (and at a brighter level) than surrounding pixels. So these burned in pixels have basically aged (worn out) faster than the others. I do not see how that could be reversed. What can be done is to age the other pixels as well, then you would not see a brightness difference anymore. This does assume that the additional aging of the burned in pixels doesn't cause them to degrade even more. So I guess, the app could work but you'd be aging your whole display.

Comment: The type of app the original poster mentioned might not be "snake oil". This type of app works by wearing down the entire display so that the non-uniformity is less visible. In other words, it makes the less-bright portions of the display less visible by making the entire display less visible. Only the user can decide if that is an acceptable solution.

Comment: My understanding of the apps is that the OLED is worn down to a lower common denominator.  Compared to identical model phones, one which ran that kind of app does indeed seem dimmer than the others.  Almost an f-stop.  But that is only a sample size of one and the phones did not have identical use.